# How do you change the url that Google Analytics' In-Page Analytics displays?

Tags: google, google-analytics

In Google Analytics, from the dashboard, clicking 'Content' in the left hand pane, and then clicking 'In-Page Analytics' brings up an awesome interface for seeing where users have actually clicked in the site.  **However**, it seems to only bring up the root page.  From there, I can navigate to other pages by clicking on the links myself, but I can't figure out how to display In-Page analytics for a page that I can't navigate to just by clicking, for example /products/red-shoes.

So, how do I change the url for which in-page analytics are being displayed?  Hopefully there's just something simple I am missing.

Comment: Maybe not an answer, but maybe a solution. I find that if I turn on in-page analytics and then in another Chrome tab I navigate to a page on our site the analytics appear automatically. Mostly this is a pain, but it may be what you want.

Comment: Paul,  I'm a little confused.  You open a new tab, and by navigating in it, the in-page analytics tab navigates with you?  Do you have a plugin for that?  It doesn't seem technically possible.  I just tried, and did not get those results.

Comment: I don't have a plugin. I agree that it doesn't seem possible, but it does happen! If it doesn't happen for you (are you using Chrome by the way?) then it's not a solution. Sorry I can't help.

Comment: I would try Paul's suggestion as i have experienced the same "issue" / solution. Its a pain when you don't want it but should help with the above. (no plugin required and works in firefox)

Answer (score 3):

Paul is right, once you are in the report you can browse to other pages through a seperate tab and wait for in-page analytics to load.

Answer (score 0):

yes it worked for me - I had analytics already on in-page diagnostics, then in a new window I opened my website and it immediately brought in analytics on the page and I could navigate through the website looking at the analytics !